# Java - Download zip file from url

Tags: java, file, zip, download

I have a problem with downloading a zip file from an url.
It works well with firefox but with my app I have a 404.

Here is my code

```
URL url = new URL(reportInfo.getURI().toString());
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Check for errors
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
InputStream inputStream;
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    inputStream = con.getInputStream();
} else {
    inputStream = con.getErrorStream();
}

OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("test.zip");

// Process the response
BufferedReader reader;
String line = null;
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    output.write(line.getBytes());
}

output.close();
inputStream.close();
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You shouldn't be making a URL with `reportInfo.getURI().toString()`, use `reportInfo.getURI().toURL()`

Answer (score 4):

In Java 7, the easiest way to save a URL to a file is:

```
try (InputStream stream = con.getInputStream()) {
    Files.copy(stream, Paths.get("test.zip"));
}
```

Comment: what is `con` part of?

Comment: @Robbo_UK `con` is defined in the second line of the original question's code.

Comment: ahh I see it now.  my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As for why you're getting a 404 - that hard to tell. You should check the value of `url`, which as greedybuddha says, you should get via `URI.getURL()`. But it's also possible that the server is using a user agent check or something similar to determine whether or not to give you the resource. You could try with something like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to fetch in programmatic way but without having to write any code yourself.

However, there another problem looming. It's a zip file. That's binary data. But you're using `InputStreamReader`, which is designed for *text* content. Don't do that. You should *never* use a `Reader` for binary data. Just use the `InputStream`:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024]; // Or whatever
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Note that you should close the streams in `finally` blocks, or use the try-with-resources statement if you're using Java 7.

Comment: @bksoux: I don't know whether you've read my most recent version - try fetching it with cURL. If you're getting a 404 response then the problem can't be in the actual reading part... but we can't do much to help you diagnose why you're getting a 404.