# Not able to Iterate over zip file downloaded from private git in JAVA

Tags: git, zipinputstream

I have small piece of code which downloads a zip file from github.  I have inserted the token in this format https://token:x-oauth-basic@github.xxxx.com/org/repo/archive/branch.zip.   The download works but when I do

```
ZipInputStream zis = ZipInputStream new FileInputStream(new FileInputStream(downloadedfilepath));
ZipEntry entry = null;
while ((entry=zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
       System.out.println("Reached"); 
}
```

zis.getNextEntry() returns null though there is lot of content in the zip. 
This code works for any other zip but does not work for zips downloaded from github using a token.

Any help would really appricate.

Comment: Can you open the zip with any other tools (Winzip or `zip` from the command line)?

Comment: when I download it manually I am able to unzip.

But when downloaded using the above method using tokenxxxx I am not able to manually unzip it. The zip turns into a .zip.cpgz  which indicates it to be corrupted. 

This is my Code to download.. 
    
    URL url = new URL(fileURL);
    HttpsURLConnection httpsUrl = (HttpsURLConnection)   url.openConnection();
    httpsUrl.connect();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(httpsUrl.getInputStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetTempFile);

Comment: Now we got your issue :-) Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16946066/981284

Comment: Pefect Thanks rlegendi

'code'
URL url = new URL(fileURL);
  URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
  String token = xxx:xxxx";
  String authorizationString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String(token.getBytes());
  uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", authorizationString);
  InputStream instream = uc.getInputStream();
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetTempFile);

and add commons-codec dependency.